# Disable S.M.A.R.T. in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, smart

Before anyone tells me not to disable S.M.A.R.T I've confirmed in the BIOS that the drive is actually reporting it's okay. Windows is misreading whatever reports S.M.A.R.T. status.

I would like to know how to disable S.M.A.R.T. errors in Windows 7. I'm using the RTM version of Windows 7.

I know it's possible to disable the reporting in Windows XP and Vista I just don't remember how I did it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Solution: After choosing "Tell me later" on the error popup several times I was presented with a third option to ignore the problem.

I choose the option to ignore and the popup hasn't appeared since. A little research shows that this behavior is also present in Vista not just Windows 7.

Comment: +1 Well there you go!. Glad I learned something new :) You should set your own answer as the accepted one if indeed you feel comfortable with your findings. I'm personally very suspicious of any SMART errors, so I wouldn't be so dismissive without at least having tried another tool to test the disk. Meanwhile this behavior is even present on Windows XP and Linux. It's not uncommon, but neither it is unheard of. You should keep an eye on new drivers/flash for your BIOS, controller and chipset. That's where these problems are finally fixed.

Comment: Is there a way to reverse the "ignore", by any chance?

Answer (score 7):

I know this thread is a bit old, but perhaps someone will still find this useful.  I chose "Tell me later" at least a couple dozen times and never got the third option to ignore the problem.  I kept getting this popup even after disabling SMART checking in the BIOS, so yes, Windows can do its own check separate from the BIOS.  Leaving aside arguments for why you shouldn't disable SMART checking, here's what to do (Windows 7):

Start Menu -> All Programs -> Accessories -> System Tools -> Task Scheduler
In Task Scheduler, expand "Task Scheduler Library" in the upper left corner.  Next, expand "Microsoft", then "Windows".  Select "DiskDiagnostic" from the list.  You should now see two items in the top middle frame.  The second item, "Microsoft-Windows-DiskDiagnosticResolver", is responsible for reporting drive errors.  You can either disable it or configure it to run less frequently than every logon.

Answer (score 6):

Most probably the problem is in the windows communications with the HD. Before disabling SMART reporting, I'd suggest checking to see if there are any new BIOS, HD driver or chipset driver updates for your computer.

Meanwhile, or if there are no updates, get also your own S.M.A.R.T. reporting tool and trust its results. **[GSmartControl](http://gsmartcontrol.berlios.de)** is one such tool. Freeware and allows you to both check current status and perform any built-in tests supported by your HD. This is better than the BIOS page own ad-hoc reporting.

To actually disable SMART, well you do it on the BIOS. You cannot disable it in Windows. I'm not sure what you mean by forgetting how you disabled the reporting in the past. It's possible you know something I don't, but I never heard of anyone able to disable S.M.A.R.T error reporting on windows.

Comment: The BIOS has built in hard drive testing. It reports the drive is fine. Windows is reading is as if the drive is failing. I can't disable S.M.A.R.T. in the bios.

Comment: Late to this party, but the BIOS relies on the drive's SMART status indicator. The OS ignores the drive, and instead relies on statistical analysis. The drive manufacturer has a vested interest in not giving you early-warning of a failure (warranty replacement), thus most drives have an extremely high warning threshold. The OS, on the other hand, has a vested interest in early-warning to prevent OS failure.

Answer (score 0):

I have better solution to be definitive. Locate on your system the **DFDWiz.exe** and rename it to **DFDWiz.exe.old** Or **DFDWiz.bkp** your choice and Ready had received never this warning on windows system tested in windows7 - Windows8 and 8.1 I used a linux distro to access and rename the file because the windows says it is being used. Good luck use at your own risk I have a hd with errors over two years and still works.

Comment: Please write in English on this site: [Do posts have to be in English on Stack Exchange?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13676/do-posts-have-to-be-in-english-on-stack-exchange) I assume you are taking regular backups of the faulty driven - and note that the backups themselves could be faulty.