# Why can't smartmontools disable SMART check?

Tags: windows, smart

When I use `smartctl -s off /dev/sda` with admin privilege, the SMART support is said to be disable:

```
C:\Program Files\smartmontools\bin>smartctl -s off /dev/sda
smartctl 6.5 2016-05-07 r4318 [i686-w64-mingw32-win8.1] (sf-6.5-1)
Copyright (C) 2002-16, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF ENABLE/DISABLE COMMANDS SECTION ===
SMART Disabled. Use option -s with argument 'on' to enable it.
```

It is confirmed by using `smartctl -a /dev/sda/`:

```
C:\Program Files\smartmontools\bin>smartctl -a /dev/sda
smartctl 6.5 2016-05-07 r4318 [i686-w64-mingw32-win8.1] (sf-6.5-1)
Copyright (C) 2002-16, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Family:     Hitachi/HGST Travelstar Z5K320
Device Model:     Hitachi HTS543232A7A384
Serial Number:    E2034243EEG7TP
LU WWN Device Id: 5 000cca 690e24d54
Firmware Version: ES2OA60W
User Capacity:    320,072,933,376 bytes [320 GB]
Sector Size:      512 bytes logical/physical
Rotation Rate:    5400 rpm
Form Factor:      2.5 inches
Device is:        In smartctl database [for details use: -P show]
ATA Version is:   ATA8-ACS T13/1699-D revision 6
SATA Version is:  SATA 2.6, 3.0 Gb/s
Local Time is:    Tue Jan 17 23:10:55 2017 SEAST
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Disabled

SMART Disabled. Use option -s with argument 'on' to enable it.
```

But when I restart my computer, the SMART check comes back again. Why is that?

My BIOS version is [1.31](https://www.acer.com/ac/vi/VN/content/support-product/2434?b=1), and there is no SMART option in it (only D2D recovery).

Comment: What do you mean by "when I restart it"? What is the "it" you are talking about?

Comment: I mean the computer

Comment: What is your outer problem? Why is it a problem if a reboot enables SMART support?

Comment: Well, my disc has some bad sector and the SMART check keeps interrupting the booting. I would like to disable it.

Comment: Well then you have no choice but to do it in the BIOS and if your BIOS provides no way to do it, you're out of luck. No OS software can run during or before booting.

Comment: but if so, then why this tool exists?

Comment: To change the current settings after the OS has booted.

Comment: but I thought that the SMART should check before the OS boots?

Comment: To the extent that happens, it's the BIOS that does it.

Comment: I know. What I mean is that if the check is executed by the BIOS only, then there's no way "to change the current settings after the OS has booted"

Comment: Exactly. As far as the BIOS's use of SMART goes, there's no opportunity for the OS or any tool hosted on it to do anything about it since it hasn't had a chance to run yet. If you want to control how the BIOS uses SMART, you have to configure that in the BIOS if it supports it. If not, you're out of luck. You're using a tool that doesn't interact with the BIOS at all, so it's the wrong tool for the job -- it can't do anything until the BIOS has already finished the booting process.

Comment: Err, are you saying that this tool is a fake? There are many suggestions in the question [Disable S.M.A.R.T. in Windows 7?](http://superuser.com/q/55146/301042)

Comment: No, the tool is real. It just doesn't do what you happen to need to do for the reason I explained. It's no good for your specific problem to disable SMART after the OS has booted, right? So how could a tool to disable SMART that you can only run after the OS has booted possibly help with your problem?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52061/discussion-between-ooker-and-david-schwartz).